# Variables in Tag manager sometimes fires and sometimes not

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm tagging a new website, and I'm running with some problems.

At first, i used the click URL to differentiate different buttons, but it only fires 1/5 times approx, some times more sometimes less. So the IT team gave the click elements specific values, but I'm still encountering with the same problem. Is it a gtm problem or a website issue? how could I fix it?.. ill leave two images attached one when it fires correctly and the other when it doesn't.

*here it's NOT working
[image]

here it is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is completely dependent on how the website is built. If your IT team could add ID to the elements that you are interested in tracking that will populate the variable Click ID. That is usually best practice and helps you to uniquely identify each component, whether it is a button or a header.